# How can I convert mysql's TIMESTAMP(2) to php's timestamp format, without losing the decimals?

Tags: php

When I use strtotime() on a mysql TIMESTAMP with 2 decimals, it converts to the Unix timestamp integer.

Is there a proper way of converting is so I get something like 1611026773.18?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

```
$ts = '1989-12-15 16:27:36.4566';
$dt = new DateTime($ts);

# 629713656.4566
echo (double)$dt->format('U.u');

# 1989-12-15 16:27:36.456600
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```